# How do I add a tap gesture to a collection view item in .net maui 8?

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

I have a *CollectionView* being used on an app that I have converted from Xamarin to MAUI (.NET 8.0):

XAML:

```xml
<CollectionView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
    SelectionMode="Single" Style="{StaticResource cardListView}" 
    Margin="6,0" 
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    x:Name="collectionView"
>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="cases:CaseCardItemModel">
            <SwipeView Margin="{OnPlatform '0,7', Android='0,0', iOS='0,7'}">
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference collectionView}, Path= BindingContext.ItemSelectedCommand}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                        />
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <containers:CardView Title="{Binding Name}" Description="{Binding Description}" Image="{Binding Image}" Disabled="{Binding Disabled}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </SwipeView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

However, No matter what I try, I can't quite get the tap gesture command binding right in order to fire this event method on the respective view model:

Command from ViewModel:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
public async void ItemSelected(CaseCardItemModel item)
{
    await OnItemSelected(item);
}
```

Now, the reason why I am wiring up events in this manner instead of using the "SelectionChanged" event is because I want the same collection view item to be clickable again when the user navigates back to the page that this collection view is on when pressing the navigation bar back button on the page that the said item navigated to. Obviously, the "SelectionChanged" event won't fire until the selection on the collection view has changed which is not what I want.

I have tried the following configurations based off of some google searches to no avail:

**Attempt 1**:

Collection View w/ x:Name:

```xml
<CollectionView 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
   SelectionMode="Single" 
   Style="{StaticResource cardListView}" 
   Margin="6,0" 
   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
   x:Name="collectionView"
 >
</CollectionView>
```

Tap Gesture inside data template:

```xml
<TapGestureRecognizer
   Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference collectionView}, Path= BindingContext.ItemSelectedCommand}" 
   CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
/>
```

**Attempt 2:**

Tap Gesture inside data template:

```xml
<TapGestureRecognizer
    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={Type cases:CaseDetailsViewModel}}, Path= ItemSelectedCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
/>
```

**Attempt 3:**

Note, this was suggested from the following article on the Microsoft Q&A forums: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1160138/image-tapgesturerecognizer-not-working-inside-coll

Name added to base page:

```xml
<containers:MenuPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    x:Name="CaseSelectionBase"
    >
```

Tap Gesture inside data template:

```xml
<TapGestureRecognizer
    Command="{Binding BindingContext.ItemSelectedCommand, Source={x:Reference CaseSelectionBase}}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
/>
```

Am I just doing something stupid? Or is this yet *another* bug in the MAUI framework that needs to be opened up. Any advice on this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can just set the SelectedItem to null in order to allow repeat selection

Comment: No that won't work, because the item has a route that needs to be fed into the OnItemSelected(item) method of the view model in order to navigate to the next page. I should have posted the code on this my bad.

Comment: try turning the selection mode to none so the collection won't override the inner control's gestures. Or look into Sharpnado's collection view that has a tapped command

Comment: There should be multiple ways around that problem

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys. I will look into the collection view this evening, and then I will report back to you. I did try the first method that Shababoo recommended, but that didn't work, by the way.

Comment: @mbai can you say more about why you think Jason's first comment wouldn't work? I'm wondering why you couldn't just capture the bound object instance corresponding to the selected collection view "item", and then once you are holding the actual object (with its routing information and so on) what difference would it really make to set the `SelectedItem` (a cosmetic distinction at this point) back to null?

Comment: the issue is that setting the selected item to nothing or even a different value means the selected index event WILL fire again. However, below, I show a simple solution in which we simple null out the selected index, and deal with the fact that the selected index changed event WILL trigger again as a result. But, it means we un-selected the row, and done so with ease, and that's all that really matters here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple "blowing out" the current selection would suffice here, and that would then allow you to "return" to the page, and click on the "same" row again.

Take this setup:

```
    <CollectionView x:Name="MyColview" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    MaximumHeightRequest="700"
                    SelectionChanged="MyColview_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single"
                    >
        <CollectionView.Header>
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="100,100,100,150,200">

                <Label Text="First" Grid.Column="0" FontAttributes="Italic,Bold" />
                <Label Text="Last" Grid.Column="1" FontAttributes="Italic,Bold" />
                <Label Text="City" Grid.Column="2" FontAttributes="Italic,Bold" />
                <Label Text="HotelName" Grid.Column="3" FontAttributes="Italic,Bold" />
                <Label Text="Description" Grid.Column="4" FontAttributes="Italic,Bold" />
            </Grid>
        </CollectionView.Header>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid  ColumnDefinitions="100,100,100,150,200" Padding="0,5,0,5">
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding City}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding HotelName}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Description}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <BoxView  Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Margin="0,-4,0,0"
                         Color="SkyBlue"
                         MinimumHeightRequest="1" MaximumHeightRequest="1" HeightRequest="1" 
                         VerticalOptions="Start"
                         />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

So, we use the "regular" Selectionchanged event.

My row click code looks like this:

```
private async void MyColview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyColview.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        tblHotel MySelHotel = (tblHotel)MyColview.SelectedItem;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new EditHotel(MySelHotel, this));
        MyColview.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```

So, note close in above how I "blow out" and set the selection to null. Keep in mind, that changing the selected item to null WILL trigger the selection changed event again, but by wrapping the code in a null check, then it works fine.

So, I pass the current row object and "form" to the next page.

On my target page, I have this:

```
public tblHotel MyHotel { get; set; }

TestHotels frmPrevious;

public EditHotel(tblHotel MyH, TestHotels frmP)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyHotel = MyH;
    frmPrevious = frmP;
    BindingContext = MyHotel;
}

private void cmdTest_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayAlert("City", MyHotel.City, "ok");
}

void MyClose()
{
    dbLocal.con.Update(MyHotel);
    frmPrevious.MyRefresh();

}
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    MyClose();
    return false;
}
```

(a bit of extra test code - but you get the idea here).

And my layout? Again, probably not all that important, but I have this:

```
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="400,400">

    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="0"
    HorizontalOptions="Start" Padding="20"
       MinimumWidthRequest="380"
                         >

        <Label>HotelName</Label>
        <Editor
        Text="{Binding HotelName}"/>

        <Label>First Name</Label>
        <Editor
        Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>

        <Label>Last Name</Label>
        <Editor
        Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>

        <Label>City</Label>
        <Editor
        Text="{Binding City}"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>

    <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="1"
    Padding="20"
    HorizontalOptions="Start"
    MinimumWidthRequest="380"
                     >

        <Label>Description</Label>
        <Editor            
        Text="{Binding Description}"
        HeightRequest="200"
        />

        <Button Text="Test Button"
                x:Name="cmdTest"
                Clicked="cmdTest_Clicked"
                />


    </VerticalStackLayout>

</Grid>
```

So, when I run, I get this effect, and note how I am able to click the 2nd row again when I return:

[image]

Comment: I did not think of that. Let me try that. Thanks Albert.

Comment: Thanks Albert! I got it to work using the OnAppearing event and then adding some more code to my view model to get it to work. I will post my code in the morning for everyone else to see how I solved this.

Comment: The setting of selected row to null looks to be a rather simple solution,  and no additional events code is required.  All my additional code not really relevant.  This question is timely since I needed the very same functionality you were asking for,  and additional things like a whole new gesture is quite a bit of extra moving parts that's not really required

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in which my collectionView does not recognize the gesture. I checked using the code behind and it works OK, but not on the MVVM. It seems the problem was with the call for the command; the problem is the route; it is looking inside the CollectionView which look the collection of the Model, but your command resides at the ViewModel level, so you should look up; in my case, I look at the page label.

The following link explains things in a better way.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1160138/image-tapgesturerecognizer-not-working-inside-coll

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).